# python flask serve several pictures by list

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

Ok, so let's say I use listdir to make an object of pictures, their names, sizes and their file names. The object is parsed so that each file name is item.values()[0]['item'].  I am trying to do:

```
{% for item in banners %}
    <h3>{{item.keys()[0]}} size {{item.values()[0]['size']}}:</h3>
    <div>
        <img src="{{url_for( 'static', filename= 'banners/{{item.values()[0]["item"]}}' )}}" />
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

But it is not working, replacing {{item.values()[0]["item"]}} with a specific file name is working and I can see that the file names are in the object, yet it will not generate the image, instead it says it failed to load the given url and the urls are weird, for example one shows up like:

```
<img src="/static/banners/%7B%7Bitem.values%28%29%5B0%5D%5B%22item%22%5D%7D%7D%7Csafe">
```

Something to do with it interpreting the characters as is instead of what they are to represent, but I cannot figure out the syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in a {{ }} block, so nesting more of those is incorrect. I think it should be something in the lines of :

`filename = 'banners/' + item.values()[0]["item"]`